# How to toggle prop 'disabled' in jquery

Tags: jquery

I like to enable and disable button control. If its disabled then enabled it and if enabled then disable it.

I have tried this with no luck;

```
$('#txtItemQty').prop('disabled', !$('#txtItemQty').prop('disabled'));
```

**Update**

I am calling following method before the above code of line. Is there a way to disable all inputs but not '#txtItemQty' in the following line of code?

```
    $('#rptDiv').css({ 'opacity': '1', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity =  100)' }).find('input, button, select').prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/au4smL68/. Please add a snippet to the question containing all relevant code to create the problem. Also check that there's only 1 element in the DOM with that id

Comment: You can also check if there are any errors showing in the developer console!

Comment: @user1263981 check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#txtItemQty').prop('disabled', function(index, val) { return !val; });
```

You can see more on this here

https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function

**Update:**

check `:not` selector https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/  below code should exclude the specific Id

```
 $('#rptDiv').css({ 'opacity': '1', 'filter': 'alpha(opacity =  100)' }).find('input:not(#txtItemQty), button, select').prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: While this is much better in approach, the OPs original should still work. As such there's likely an underlying problem which this doesn't address

Comment: I just posted the usual working approach we follow for similar scenario, but you are right his code should work !